# Iterate over array with LINQ and use the value at each position

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

I'm using .NET 4.6.1

I have a property with which I can get and set the width of each column in a `DataGridView`:

```
public int[] MyDataGridViewColWidth
{
    get
    {
        return myDataGridView.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Select(c => c.Width).ToArray();
    }
    set
    {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < value.Length; pos++)
        {
            myDataGridView.Columns[pos].Width = value[pos];
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the getter uses a LINQ expression to retrieve all column widths in an array.

Is the reverse in the setter also applicable for LINQ or should I stick to the primitive for loop?

Comment: What is primitive in a loop? Use it whenever you want to modify multiple things. A LIN**Q** query should not cause side effects. It should only be used to query and return something.

Comment: LINQ is just for writing small code internally once it's compiled its all same thing.

Comment: I'd stick with the `for` loop.  Thought you might want to add some checks in the `set` for `null` and an `array` that is longer than the number of columns.

Comment: @RICKYKUMAR: OP is asking about the set accessor. There is no LINQ equivalent which compiles to the same thing. For a good reason: LIN(Q) queries sources and doesn't modify them.

Comment: Yes you could use LINQ in the setter but i'd stick to the solution you have now. As previously mentioned you might want to add some error checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

technically it is possible to use LINQ here

```
set
{
    value.Select((i, pos) => myDataGridView.Columns[pos].Width = i).Last();
}
```

`Last()` forces enumeration of entire sequence. The sequence consists of values, produced by assignment expression `myDataGridView.Columns[pos].Width = i`. Those values are ignored, because only side effect (changing `myDataGridView.Columns[pos].Width`) is important in this context

however `for` often rules them [LINQ extensions] all in terms of simplicity and portability. LINQ isn't meant to produce side effects. And it is .NET specific, outside .NET one has to use `for`. I would stick to existing implementation.

Answer (score -1):

When you using LINQ or ForEach loops, which both rely on IEnumerable you should not modify the container you are iterating through during the loop.  If you want to change the values you need to use a for loop.  Linked post from MSDN that talks about it better than I could

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a90c87be-9553-4d48-9892-d482ee325f02/why-cant-change-value-in-foreach?forum=csharpgeneral

Edit*
Please note that the above reference to values is specifically referring to the container that you are iterating through.  You can change "values" as long as you are not trying to change the container, meaning in the foreach (item in items) you cannot change the value "item".  This point is pretty granular but the commenters below are correct that the above could be misleading.

Comment: You can modify the values during enumeration in a `foreach`-loop. You just can't change the source of the item(for example add or remove items from the collection that you are enumerating). A `foreach`-loop is a perfect tool to modify the item whereas a LINQ query is not.

Comment: Your answer is misleading. You can modify values in a loop, just not the data that is being looped over.

Comment: Most folks asking questions here are pretty new to C#....at some point we have to balance precision and readability for new developers.  The reality is the answer to the thread is the difference between direct access using indexing and using an enumerator, which isn't a simple concept for new developers.  The link describes this pretty well, but trying to distinguish this by using precise language will lose people.  For those who have worked with enumerators for years this distinction might not be complex, but for some it is.